# where to put applicationcontext.xml and .hbm files?

Tags: spring, hibernate, zk

I'm learning spring hibernate zk stack, and doing my first crud following [this tutorial](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/December/Integrate_ZK5_with_Spring_3_and_Hibernate)
I put applicationContext.xml into webapp/WEB-INF, and .hbm.xml to resources/mappings
But I dont know why my hbm files keep showing can not find my pojos.

in github https://github.com/kossel/firstzk

I have this structure

[image]

applicationContext.xml

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- set other Hibernate properties in hibernate.cfg.xml file -->
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/com/iknition/firstzk/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <mapping resource="com/iknition/firstzk/hibernate/Company.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="com/iknition/firstzk/hibernate/Contact.hbm.xml" />
```

Company.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.iknition.firstzk.beans">
    <class name="Contact" table="contact">
        <id name="idcontact" column="idcontact" type="integer">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
        <property name="email" column="email" type="string" />
        <many-to-one name="company" column="companyId" class="com.iknition.firstzk.beans.Company" outer-join="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Contact.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.iknition.firstzk.beans">
    <class name="Contact" table="contact">
        <id name="idcontact" column="idcontact" type="integer">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
        <property name="email" column="email" type="string" />
        <many-to-one name="company" column="companyId" class="com.iknition.firstzk.beans.Company" outer-join="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**UPDATE:**

- I have reference to contact.hbm.xml too, I missed to put it here.
- by "*why my hbm files keep showing can not find my pojos*" I mean, when I try to build the application, I keep getting error of "`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: com.iknition.firstzk.beans.Contact`" I have changed many times the location of those configuration files, and still getting same error.

Comment: Can you extend this: "*why my hbm files keep showing can not find my pojos*"? What problem are you experiencing? Also you are only referencing `Company.hbm.xml` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`. What about `Contact.hbm.xml`?

Comment: sorry, I have updated the question to clarify what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify mappingLocations one-by-one like:

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
  <util:list>
    <value>hibernate/Company.hbm.xml</value>
    <value>hibernate/Contact.hbm.xml</value>
  </util:list>
</property>
```

Comment: Tried annotation and worked, then I to changed to your suggestion and worked too! :D

Comment: Ok. Look at docs for the LocalSessionFactoryBean. It requires an array of Resource[] s. And you can not link at them with *.hbm.xml.

Comment: Annotations were not proper since you'd configured project for Java 1.4 in pom.xml

Comment: you are correct, I changed it to jdk 1.6. but for every configuration path, I have to prepend the word "classpath:" in order to make them work, even they are all in resource folder. ej. i had to put 'classpath:hibernate/Contact.hbm.xml' or it will not compile because file not found exception

Comment: If you use the 'mappingResources' property, you are correct, but if I believe that 'mappingLocations' allows a wildcard notation.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... never tried using an external hibernate.cfg.xml. But I think specifying that only loads the properties. You might still need to set the mapping in a separate property.

Here's what my config usually looks like:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="propertiesArray">
                <list>
                    <props>...</props>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:com/iknition/firstzk/hibernate/*.hbm.xml"/>

</bean>
```

Comment: I have been playing with location and configuration applicationContext file, and I still got the same error. I have updated the question. I suspect the problem is in my .hbm configuration