# Hibernate reverse engineering, using in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I just used Hibernate reverse engineering to  reverse engineer my project and I see that it created a number of POJO java classes and alot of *.hbm.xml files.

in the past my java code looked like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enrollment")
public class Enrollment {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "enrollment_id")
    private Integer enrollment_id;

    @Column(name = "file_num")
    private String file_num;

    @Column(name = "eis_num")
    private String eis_num;

    @Column(name = "enrollment_type_id")
    private String enrollment_type_id;

    @Column(name = "ssn")
    private String ssn; 

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @Column(name = "middle_initial")
    private String middle_initial;

    @Column(name = "contact_id")
    private Integer contact_id;

    @Column(name = "retired_date")
    private String retired_date;

    @Column(name = "deferred_date")
    private String deferred_date;

    @Column(name = "school_id")
    private String school_id;

    @Column(name = "borough_id")
    private String borough_id;

    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    private String profile_id;

    @Column(name = "current_status")
    private String current_status;

    @Column(name = "last_update")
    private String last_update;

    @Column(name = "entry_date")
    private String entry_date;

    public void setProfile_id(String profile_id) {
        this.profile_id = profile_id;
    }   

    public Integer getEnrollment_id() {
        return enrollment_id;
    }

    public void setEnrollment_id(Integer enrollment_id) {
        this.enrollment_id = enrollment_id;
    }

    public String getFile_num() {
        return file_num;
    }

    public void setFile_num(String file_num) {
        this.file_num = file_num;
    }

    public String getEis_num() {
        return eis_num;
    }

    public void setEis_num(String eis_num) {
        this.eis_num = eis_num;
    }

    public String getEnrollment_type_id() {
        return enrollment_type_id;
    }

    public void setEnrollment_type_id(String enrollment_type_id) {
        this.enrollment_type_id = enrollment_type_id;
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getMiddle_initial() {
        return middle_initial;
    }

    public void setMiddle_initial(String middle_initial) {
        this.middle_initial = middle_initial;
    }

    public Integer getContact_id() {
        return contact_id;
    }

    public void setContact_id(Integer contact_id) {
        this.contact_id = contact_id;
    }

    public String getRetired_date() {
        return retired_date;
    }

    public void setRetired_date(String retired_date) {
        this.retired_date = retired_date;
    }

    public String getDeferred_date() {
        return deferred_date;
    }

    public void setDeferred_date(String deferred_date) {
        this.deferred_date = deferred_date;
    }

    public String getSchool_id() {
        return school_id;
    }

    public void setSchool_id(String school_id) {
        this.school_id = school_id;
    }

    public String getBorough_id() {
        return borough_id;
    }

    public void setBorough_id(String borough_id) {
        this.borough_id = borough_id;
    }



    public String getCurrent_status() {
        return current_status;
    }

    public void setCurrent_status(String current_status) {
        this.current_status = current_status;
    }

    public String getLast_update() {
        return last_update;
    }

    public void setLast_update(String last_update) {
        this.last_update = last_update;
    }

    public String getEntry_date() {
        return entry_date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Enrollment [enrollment_id=" + enrollment_id + ", file_num="
                + file_num + ", eis_num=" + eis_num + ", enrollment_type_id="
                + enrollment_type_id + ", ssn=" + ssn + ", first_name="
                + first_name + ", last_name=" + last_name + ", middle_initial="
                + middle_initial + ", contact_id=" + contact_id
                + ", retired_date=" + retired_date + ", deferred_date="
                + deferred_date + ", school_id=" + school_id + ", borough_id="
                + borough_id + ", profile_id=" + profile_id
                + ", current_status=" + current_status + ", last_update="
                + last_update + ", entry_date=" + entry_date
                + ", getEnrollment_id()=" + getEnrollment_id()
                + ", getFile_num()=" + getFile_num() + ", getEis_num()="
                + getEis_num() + ", getEnrollment_type_id()="
                + getEnrollment_type_id() + ", getSsn()=" + getSsn()
                + ", getFirst_name()=" + getFirst_name() + ", getLast_name()="
                + getLast_name() + ", getMiddle_initial()="
                + getMiddle_initial() + ", getContact_id()=" + getContact_id()
                + ", getRetired_date()=" + getRetired_date()
                + ", getDeferred_date()=" + getDeferred_date()
                + ", getSchool_id()=" + getSchool_id() + ", getBorough_id()="
                + getBorough_id() + ", getCurrent_status()="
                + getCurrent_status() + ", getLast_update()="
                + getLast_update() + ", getEntry_date()=" + getEntry_date()
                + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode()
                + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }

    public void setEntry_date(String entry_date) {
        this.entry_date = entry_date;
    }


}
```

but the code that the Hibernate reverse engineering create dont have any of the @Entity, @Table or @Column tags it looks like all the mappings are in the hbm.xml.  How do I use them in a Spring MVC project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the hbm.xml files, include it in the applicationContext and use it in the project. The only difference is that all the mappings will be present in the hbm file. Where as you had them as annotations in your code.

Your application Context should look like this:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                          <!-- All your hbms --><value>yourHbmFile.hbm.xml</value>

            </list>
        </property>
..
.
</bean>
```

Also if you want to map a directory which contains all the hbm's you can use:

```
<property name="mappingDirectoryLocations" value="classpath:org/../hibernate/model" />
```

Comment: yes. but this is what I mean.. I have about 200 files.. where do I add them?

Comment: Do you have an application context.xml file where you declare all your beans?

Comment: so do I change this... <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>org.uftwf.loadtester.model.Profile</value>
    <value>org.uftwf.loadtester.model.School</value>
   </list>
  </property>

Comment: You can create a hibernate configuration file and place all you mappings in that file and link it to your application context if the hibernate reverse engineering tool haven't generated any configuration file. Here is a link for your reference. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741841/where-to-put-applicationcontext-xml-and-hbm-files

Comment: Yes, to find all the annotated classes you can component scans which scans a particular package and automatically maps all the @Entity 's

Comment: so this sounds easy.. all I have to do is change annotatedClasses to mappingResources and put *.hbm.xml is this right

Comment: I never used it that way, but you can give it a try. Instead why not stick to the annotations? Any specific reason to go the hbm route? Also to find annotated classes you can use this in your app context:<context:annotation-config/>  
  <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans. 
         -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf.loadtester.model"/>

Comment: we are trying to use Hibernate reverse engineering and it makes the hbm.xml files for a large project we are on

Comment: You should be able to map a directory which contains all the hbms using: <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
      <list>
        <value>
          com/…/domain/
        </value>
      </list>
</property> (according to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916467/embed-hibernate-hbm-xml-mappings-in-jar)

Comment: You can generate annotated classes from the tables in eclipse using JPA if you are looking for a tool to generate entities from tables.